# C# get custom attribute extension method

Tags: c#, mongodb, json.net

can someone help me to create an extension method for custom attributes for newtonsoft.json and mongodb?

Let's say I've following class:

```
public class Foo
{
    [BsonElement("MyCustomDbName")]
    [JsonProperty("MyCustomJsonName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

How to create an extension method to get the following:

```
var myFoo = new Foo(){Name=""};
var mongoDbElementName = myFoo.Name.GetMongoDbElementName(); // should return 'MyCustomDbName'
var jsonPropertyName = myFoo.Name.GetJsonPropertyName(); // should return 'MyCustomJsonName'
```

or directly with the class itself:

```
var mongoDbElementName = Foo.Name.GetMongoDbElementName(); // should return 'MyCustomDbName'
var jsonPropertyName = Foo.Name.GetJsonPropertyName(); // should return 'MyCustomJsonName'
```

I've tried stuff like this:

```
public static string GetMongoDbElementName(this Type modelType, PropertyInfo property)
{
    return (modelType.GetProperty(nameof(property)) ?? throw new InvalidOperationException()).GetCustomAttribute<BsonElementAttribute>()?.ElementName;
}
```

But is there a way to do it without parameter?

THX in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that directly on the property; you would need to apply the extension method to the class and use an expression to select the property:

```
public static string GetMongoDbElementName<T>(
    this T obj,
    Expression<Func<T, object>> propertySelector)
{
    var memberExpression = propertySelector.Body as MemberExpression;
    var memberName = memberExpression?.Member.Name
        ?? throw new InvalidOperationException();

    var bsonAttribute = obj
        .GetType()
        .GetProperty(memberName)
        .GetCustomAttribute<BsonElementAttribute>();

    return bsonAttribute?.ElementName;
}
```

Usage:

```
var mongoDbElementName = myFoo.GetMongoDbElementName(x => x.Name);
```

---

You may also want to update the code to guard against other members being selected (e.g. a method), which could be done like this:

```
var property = obj
    .GetType()
    .GetProperty(memberName)
    ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"{memberName} is not a property");
 
var bsonAttribute = property
    .GetCustomAttribute<BsonElementAttribute>();
```

Comment: THX, good solution!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can get an attribute and it's value using reflection:

```
public static string GetBsonElementName(this Foo foo)
{
    var bsonElementAttribute =
        typeof(Foo)
        .GetProperty(nameof(Foo.Name))
        .GetCustomAttribute<BsonElementAttribute>();

    return bsonElementAttribute.ElementName;
}

public static string GetJsonPropertyName(this Foo foo)
{
    var jsonPropertyAttribute =
        typeof(Foo)
        .GetProperty(nameof(Foo.Name))
        .GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>();

    return jsonPropertyAttribute.PropertyName;
}
```

You use it like this:

```
var foo = new Foo();
var bsonElementName = foo.GetBsonElementName();
var jsonPropertyName = foo.GetJsonPropertyName();
```

Comment: This is unlikely to be useful considering it is hardcoded to `Foo.Name`.

Comment: Also, what is [`BsonName`?](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.9/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Bson_Serialization_Attributes_BsonElementAttribute.htm)